# Resizing images by maintaining aspect ratio - loop

Tags: actionscript-3

I need some help creating a more performant code to resize images and maintain their aspect ratio. So I made an instance in Flash "Image_Placeholder" that is being used to load in images from an external XML file.

These images should fit in the placeholder of let's say 120px by 120px.

So far the code I'm using is the following:

```
function ResizeImage2(){
    image.width=120;
    image.scaleY=image.scaleX;
    image2.width=120;
    image2.scaleY=image2.scaleX;
        if(image.height>120 && image2.height>120){
           image.height=120;
           image.scaleX=image.scaleY;
            image2.height=120;
            image2.scaleX=image2.scaleY;
        }
        else if(image.height>120 && image2.height<120){
            image.height=120;
           image.scaleX=image.scaleY;

        }
        else if(image.height<120 && image2.height>120){
            image2.height=120;
            image2.scaleX=image2.scaleY;

        }
}

ResizeImage2();
```

How do I create a loop that does this function for each image? Instead of creating more else statements as more images get loaded in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
function ResizeImage(obj:Object){
    var imgname =obj;
    imgname.width=120;
    imgname.scaleY=imgname.scaleX;

        if(imgname.height>120){
        imgname.height=120;
        imgname.scaleX=imgname.scaleY;
        }
}

ResizeImage(image);
ResizeImage(image2);
```